# Blazor: Intellisense not suggesting using statements on Razor files (on Visual Studio for Mac)

Tags: razor, blazor, intellisense, visual-studio-mac

VS intellisense suggesting the namespaces to import does not seem to work for me when working with .razor files.

For example: I've already added the nuget package for Azure Blob Storage and it ought to have suggested `@using Azure.Storage.Blobs` for `BlobContainerClient` here:

[image]

I'm running Visual Studio 2019 for Mac version 8.10.11 (build 8). Also tried looking for updated in the preview channel but I'm all up to date.

> === Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac ===
>
> Version 8.10.11 (build 8) Installation UUID:
> 8041a0b7-7fe6-4d48-a2dc-52be883ab7b2  GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
> Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23 (d16-6 / 088c73638)
>
> Package version: 612000140
>
> === Mono Framework MDK ===
>
> Runtime:  Mono 6.12.0.140 (2020-02/51d876a041e) (64-bit)  Package
> version: 612000140
>
> === Roslyn (Language Service) ===
>
> 3.10.0-4.21269.26+029847714208ebe49668667c60ea5b0a294e0fcb
>
> === NuGet ===
>
> Version: 5.9.0.7134
>
> === .NET Core SDK ===
>
> SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.100-rc.2.21505.57/Sdks SDK
> Versions:
> 6.0.100-rc.2.21505.57
> 5.0.402
> 5.0.201
> 3.1.414
> 3.1.401
> 3.1.302
> 3.1.300
> 3.1.101
> 3.1.100
> 3.0.101
> 2.2.207
> 2.2.105
> 2.1.504
> 2.1.302 MSBuild SDKs: /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/MSBuild/Current/bin/Sdks
>
> === .NET Core Runtime ===
>
> Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet Runtime Versions:
> 6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5
> 5.0.11
> 5.0.4
> 3.1.20
> 3.1.7
> 3.1.6
> 3.1.4
> 3.1.1
> 3.1.0
> 3.0.1
> 2.2.8
> 2.2.3
> 2.1.23
> 2.1.21
> 2.1.20
> 2.1.18
> 2.1.15
> 2.1.14
> 2.1.8
> 2.1.2
>
> === .NET Core 3.1 SDK ===
>
> SDK: 3.1.414
>
> === Xamarin.Profiler ===
>
> Version: 1.6.13.11 Location: /Applications/Xamarin
> Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler
>
> === Updater ===
>
> Version: 11
>
> === Xamarin Designer ===
>
> Version: 16.10.0.119 Hash: 36a2d986f Branch: remotes/origin/d16-10
> Build date: 2021-06-02 19:41:34 UTC
>
> === Apple Developer Tools ===
>
> Xcode 13.0 (19234) Build 13A233
>
> === Xamarin.Mac ===
>
> Version: 7.14.0.27 (Visual Studio Community) Hash: 2566861a9 Branch:
> d16-10 Build date: 2021-07-27 02:34:12-0400
>
> === Xamarin.iOS ===
>
> Version: 15.0.0.6 (Visual Studio Community) Hash: 2771277e0 Branch:
> xcode13-ios Build date: 2021-09-23 10:36:08-0400
>
> === Xamarin.Android ===
>
> Version: 11.3.0.4 (Visual Studio Community) Commit:
> xamarin-android/d16-10/ae14caf Android SDK:
> /Users/jay/Library/Android/sdk    Supported Android versions:
> 4.4.87 (API level 20)
> 5.0    (API level 21)
> 6.0    (API level 23)
> 8.0    (API level 26)
> 8.1    (API level 27)
>
> SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1 SDK Platform Tools Version: 30.0.4 SDK Build
> Tools Version: 30.0.1
>
> Build Information:  Mono: b4a3858 Java.Interop:
> xamarin/java.interop/d16-10@f39db25 ProGuard:
> Guardsquare/proguard/v7.0.1@912d149 SQLite:
> xamarin/sqlite/3.35.4@85460d3 Xamarin.Android Tools:
> xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-10@c5732a0
>
> === Microsoft OpenJDK for Mobile ===
>
> Java SDK:
> /Users/jay/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25
> 1.8.0-25 Android Designer EPL code available here: https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL
>
> === Android SDK Manager ===
>
> Version: 16.10.0.13 Hash: 1b81df5 Branch: remotes/origin/d16-10 Build
> date: 2021-09-21 02:30:50 UTC
>
> === Android Device Manager ===
>
> Version: 16.10.0.15 Hash: 89dcc0b Branch: remotes/origin/d16-10 Build
> date: 2021-09-21 02:31:08 UTC
>
> === Build Information ===
>
> Release ID: 810110008 Git revision:
> 5467245e1f99a0c8ccdd2acea02d16c3fb65c220 Build date: 2021-10-07
> 10:49:46-04 Build branch: release-8.10
>
> === Operating System ===
>
> Mac OS X 10.16.0 Darwin 20.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0
> Wed Jun 23 00:26:31 PDT 2021
> root:xnu-7195.141.2~5/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
>
> === Enabled user installed extensions ===
>
> XAML Styler 2.0.1